# Showing a Toast message from AsyncTask using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, android-context

There are many answers on this topic already, but I am not able to get mine working.

From one of the activities, I am calling my asynctask like this:

```
DownloadChapters().execute(currentChapUrl)
```

My asynctask looks like this:

```
   class DownloadChapters() : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        
        override fun doInBackground(vararg startingChapUrl : String): String? {
            //processing.. downloading from url's etc..
            val result = "A total of $chapCount chapters Downloaded"
            return result  //I want to show this "result" as a toast message.
        }
    
//trying to showing toast message here, but I cant get the context right, is what I am guessing. Please help.
        override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            Toast.makeText(this, result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
        }
    
    }
```

The error shows at the toast function.

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun makeText(p0: Context!, p1: CharSequence!, p2: Int): Toast! defined in android.widget.Toast
public open fun makeText(p0: Context!, p1: Int, p2: Int): Toast! defined in android.widget.Toast
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is this topic? And what is the question?

Comment: You need to pass a `Context` as the first parameter of the `makeText` function. You're passing `this`, which is your `AsyncTask`. By the way, `AsyncTask` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an instance of `Context` to `DownloadChapters` when you instantiate it and use it in `onPostExecute`. Make sure it's an `applicationContext`, to avoid accidentally leaking your Activity.

```
class DownloadChapters(private val context: Context) : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
  override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)
    Toast.makeText(context, result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }
}

// In Activity
DownloadChapters(applicationContext).execute(currentChapUrl)
```

Better yet, replace your AsyncTask with Coroutines. [AsyncTask is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Comment: I have been only learning this for last few weeks. I am not sure how to pass Context to DownloadChapters. Using most popular methods(like AsyncTask) for now to learn before getting to the latest ones.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a code snippet. There's no reason to learn about AsyncTasks anymore, this is an outdated technology that should not be used in newly written code. There are major flaws with AsyncTask that make it dangerous to use.

Comment: I'm agree with @Egor coroutines makes threading easier

Comment: Thanks. Perfectly working. I will look into coroutines as well.

Comment: Woah. I replaced asynctask with Coroutine. It was so simple and very easy to switch context. great. Thank you so much for the recommendation. _/\_